# can not delay submit form to show div after validated with jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

I want to after validating form data, "thanks" div will be shown, then form submit data.
In validate code, i add :

```
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $('#contact_form').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('#thanksDiv').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                form.delay(1000).submit();
            })
        });
    }
```

but, form is not submit after thanksDiv fadeIn

Comment: I haven't tried but is `form` a jQuery Object? Try with `$(form).delay(1000).submit();`

Answer (score 0):

This works: `$(form).unbind('submit').delay(5000).submit();`